# Not allowing same JFrame to be opened twice or more

Tags: java, swing

well I made a `JComboBox` when one of it's items  is selected it launches a `JFrame`.

but if the same item is selected again even if the `JFrame` is already launched, it launches again.

how would i go about allowing it only to be open once at the same time.

thanks :)

Comment: Show your code. Set a flag/boolean or check if the `JFrame` is already visible.

Comment: thanks! i added a condition if it's not visible to allow it to be opened, otherwise it would show an error. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use custom **JDialogs** instead of Jframe which will not allow user inputs from another window or dialog. Refer [Oracle website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#button) for more information and source code.

Also you can use a static Jframe variable in a class which will hold the Jframe instance created by event, but its **not good way of coding**.

```
    //global jframe variable
    class Globals{
     public static myFrame myFrameOpenedInstance=null;
    }


// By invoking the event method returns same instance
     method duringEventOccured()
     {
      if(Globals.myFrameOpenedInstance==null){
      myFrame newFrameInstance=new myFrame();
      Globals.myFrameOpenedInstance=newFrameInstance;
      newFrameInstance.setVisible(true);
      }
     else{
      myFrame newFrameInstance=Globals.myFrameOpenedInstance; 
      newFrameInstance.setVisible(true);
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Tester extends JFrame {
  boolean i = true;

  public Tester() {
    setVisible(true);
    pack();
    JComboBox box = new JComboBox();
    box.addItem("One");
    box.addItem("Two");
    box.addItem("Three");
    box.addItem("Four");

    box.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (i) {
          final JFrame s = new JFrame();
          s.setVisible(true);
          s.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
              i = true;
              s.setEnabled(false);
            }
          });

        }
        else {
          System.out.print("\n alredy opende");
        }
        i = false;
      }
    });
    getContentPane().add(box);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tester tester = new Tester();
  }
}
```

This Demo example Which is example help to you .we add Windows Listener and also boolean variable to recognise window already opening are not.[image]